# Problem while saving gameobjects' data in XML file

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization, augmented-reality

I am trying to save gameobject's data in XML file but in XML file, I am only getting the last value from the List instead of two different values. I have instantiated two tooltips under different two different gameobjects and I am storing those instantiated tooltip's in list. When I print the text of the tooltip, I am getting two different values but when I try to save those two values in XML file, I am getting the text value of the last instantiated tooltip twice in XML file.

Model:

[image]

A model with instantiated tooltips under Handle and Key game object (Marked with red line):

[image]

Scenario:

If I have instantiated two tooltips with values "text1" and "text2" on two different objects then I want to store "text1" and "text2" values in XML file.

Below is the code.

```
 public ItemEntry newItem = new ItemEntry();
 public ItemDatabase itemDB;
 ObjectSpawnManager ObjectSpawnManager;
 
 private void Start()
 {
     ObjectSpawnManager = GetComponent<ObjectSpawnManager>();
 }
 public void SaveFeedback(GameObject parentGameObject)
 {
     foreach (GameObject go in ObjectSpawnManager.iconTooltipList)
     {
         Debug.Log(go.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshPro>().text);
         newItem.toolTipText = go.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TextMeshPro>().text;
         itemDB.list.Add(newItem);
     }
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));
     FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/Feedback Solution/feedback_data.xml", FileMode.Create);
     serializer.Serialize(stream, itemDB);
     stream.Close();
 }
 public class ItemEntry
 {
     public string toolTipText;
 }
 
 public class ItemDatabase
 {
     public List<ItemEntry> list = new List<ItemEntry>();
 }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you show us how you add the entries? And also show the Hierarchy of your according objects. Also quite redundant to use `GetComponentInChildren` twice .. you should store the string and re-use it

Comment: @derHugo..Thanks a lot for the help! I tried to put my ItemEntry newItem = new ItemEntry(); at the start of forloop and it worked. But I still would like to know if there is anything I can refactor in my code. As you suggested for GetComponentInChildren redundancy...]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it by initializing the  `public ItemEntry newItem = new ItemEntry();` under for loop and it worked for me.